# Does bonus damage from Thrown Weapon Fighting affect the ability Deflect Missiles?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, multi-classing, ranged-attack, fighting-style

All Monks of level 3 and higher have the trait "Deflect Missiles".
A Monk can multiclass into one of the classes that offer a fighting style, and take the fighting style "Thrown Weapon Fighting".

> **Deflect Missiles**
> Starting at 3rd level, you can use your reaction to deflect or catch the missile when you are hit by a ranged weapon attack. When you do so, the damage you take from the attack is reduced by 1d10 + your Dexterity modifier + your monk level.
> If you reduce the damage to 0, you can catch the missile if it is small enough for you to hold in one hand and you have at least one hand free. If you catch a missile in this way, you can spend 1 ki point to make a ranged attack with a range of 20/60 using the weapon or piece of ammunition you just caught, as part of the same reaction. You make this attack with proficiency, regardless of your weapon proficiencies, and the missile counts as a monk weapon for the attack.

> **Thrown Weapon Fighting.**
> You can draw a weapon that has the thrown property as part of the attack you make with the weapon.
> In addition, when you hit with a ranged attack using a thrown weapon, you gain a +2 bonus to the damage roll.

If a Monk, via the "Deflect Missiles" feature, was to reduce the damage of a ranged weapon attack to 0, and spend the ki point needed to make an attack with the missile, would they add a +2 to the damage roll because of thrown weapon fighting?

Comment: I appreciate the check mark, but it is a common courtesy on this site to wait 24 hours or so before accepting an answer. This gives other users a chance to leave their own answers which could be better than the ones currently available. 

Just wanted to mention it. Happy stacking!

Comment: Thank you! I was entirely unaware of that and have done the same thing already without knowing.

Answer (score 15):

### Only if the missile is a thrown weapon

Even though you are making a ranged attack with the missile, it is not necessarily considered a thrown weapon for that attack. The thrown weapon property is specific to certain weapons. Here is an excerpt from the [Basic Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties):

> If a weapon has the thrown property, you can throw the weapon to make a ranged attack. If the weapon is a melee weapon, you use the same ability modifier for that attack roll and damage roll that you would use for a melee attack with the weapon.

That being said, thrown weapons *can* be missiles, so if you are deflecting one such ranged attack, then you are "hit[ting] with a ranged attack using a thrown weapon." In this case, you would get the bonus.